# Get owner of one file, and apply it to another

Tags: linux, bash

I have this line in a script I'm creating

```
ls -l  ../$_module.php | awk '{print $3}'
```

Which simply prints out the owner of a file. Is it possible to assign the `$3` to a variable (let's call it _owner) so I can then run
`chmod $_owner $_con"Controller.php"` on a file the script is creating, so `$_con"Controller.php"` has the same owner as `$_module.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you want `chown(1)`, not `chmod(1)` to change the owner. And GNU `chown`, which you probably have if you're on Linux, has a nifty option `--reference=file` which will change the owner to be the same as in the referenced file.

---

If you insist on doing it manually, or your `chown` doesn't have that option, you can store the output as a variable and use that:

```
owner=$(some comand)
```

But be advised that `ls` does not guarantee stable output, i.e. you should not depend on the format. You might want to use `stat` as PaulProgrammer suggests.

Comment: That's better, but not universal (in case you ever find yourself on Solaris or AIX or something...)

Answer (score 3):

You really want `chown` to change the owner, and you can get the owner's user name with `stat -c %U /path/to/file`.  Using backticks, you can feed the output from `stat` into the input of `chown`:

```
chown `stat -c %U module.php` target.php
```